# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.data' has no attribute 'AUTOTUNE'

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror

I am a univ student. I am working on my graduation work using the EfficientDet model.
First of all, I am using Efficientdet model for fine tuning my custom dataset.

```
python = 3.7
tensorflow = 2.5
tensorflow-gpu = 1.15
cuda = 11.0
```

these are versions of the packages I installed,

error message is

```
   =====> Starting training, epoch: 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
W0527 01:25:16.531095 140153861850944 deprecation.py:323] From /home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 407, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "main.py", line 400, in main
    run_train_and_eval(e)
  File "main.py", line 384, in run_train_and_eval
    max_steps=e * FLAGS.num_examples_per_epoch // FLAGS.train_batch_size)
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1188, in _train_model_default
    input_fn, ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1025, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1116, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ais-public/ms_ys/Liberty/automl/efficientdet/dataloader.py", line 431, in __call__
    _prefetch_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
  File "/home/ais-public/anaconda3/envs/peace/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.data' has no attribute 'AUTOTUNE'
```

I can't find 'tensorflow/_api/v1/data' folder and I don't know why this error is occurs.
please tell me how to slove this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to find this file and line:

> File "/home/ais-public/ms_ys/Liberty/automl/efficientdet/dataloader.py", line >431, in **call**
> _prefetch_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

and change tf.data.AUTOTUNE to tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE.
You have an older tensorflow-gpu version. AUTOTUNE is no longer experimental, as far as I know.

Or try to use just tensorflow 2.5, to avoid version conflicts.